# Order of execution of RequestHandlers configured in Apache CXF and JAX-RS

Tags: rest, cxf, jax-rs

I am in process of implementing a REST API server using Apache CXF JAX-RS v(2.30). I am using spring as container. I am thinking of making use of `org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.ext.RequestHandler` to implement few features like license check, authentication, authorization (All of which has custom code). My idea is to segregate this code in individual implementation classes (implementing `RequestHandler`) and configure it for a base REST url something like `/rest/*`. Being new to Apache CXF and JAX-RS, I want to understand following things.

- Is this approach the right way to implement the features I want to?
- If yes, then is the order in which the `RequestHandler`s are declared is the order of their invocation?

For example if in my definition I declare:

```xml
<beans>
<jaxrs:server id="abcRestService" address="/rest">
    <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
      <bean class="com.abc.api.rest.service.FooService" />
    </jaxrs:serviceBeans>

    <jaxrs:providers>
      <ref bean="licenseFilter" />
      <ref bean="authorizationFilter" />
    </jaxrs:providers>

</jaxrs:server>

    <bean id="licenseFilter" class="com.abc.api.rest.providers.LicenseValidator">
        <!-- License check bean properties -->
    </bean>

    <bean id="authorizationFilter" class="com.abc.api.rest.providers.AuthorizationFilter">
        <!-- authorization bean properties -->
    </bean>
</beans>
```

then will the `licenseFilter` ***always*** get invoked before `authorizationFilter`?

I did not find a mention of invocation ordering of `RequestHandler`s as well as `ResponseHandler`s.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured this out.

It gets invoked in the order of declaration of beans in `<jaxrs:providers>`. Thus in case mentioned in question, licenseFilter will get invoked before authorizationFilter.

Comment: do you have a source where this is stated / defined?

Comment: No. I deduced this based on my tests.